# Unsure which join to use with with the following sql code

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

i have 2 tables. I am wanting to insert some values into 1 table. The fields i am updating is ingredient_Name, Ingredient_Amount and Recipe_ID.

***Ingredient (Table 1)***

```
Ingredient_Name|Ingredient_Amount|Recipe_ID
---------------|-----------------|---------  <---- Insert into here
```

***Recipe (Table 2)***

```
Recipe_Name|Recipe_ID
yummyRecipe|----1----    <-----Recipe_ID stored here
```

The form i am using has a comboBox which lists all Recipe_Names. So when i go to insert a row into ingredients i need to fetch the Recipe_ID from the Recipe table where i have selected the Recipe_Name in the comboBox. Then use this Recipe_ID for the ID in the Ingredients table.

I am not very familiar with JOINs and unsure how to work out what one to use and if i need to use one. Any help or ideas?

Sorry if this is too long winded.

***Recipe ComboBox Code***

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM Recipe", con);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            recipeCombo.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Recipe_Name"]);
        }

        dt.Clear();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }


    con.Close();
```

Comment: Why don't you store also the RecipeID in the combobox? This would avoid any problem. By the way MDF files are from Sql Server not MySql. Or your tag is wrong or your title

Comment: *using .mdf local database* is irrelevant. It doesn't matter if you're using a local database or a remote database. Also, .mdf files are SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: @Steve i know how to list the Recipe_Name in the comboBox but not with the ID. How do you do both?

Comment: Which kind of application are we talking about here? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or?

Comment: @Steve WinForms. I have updated the code above. I have included where i insert recipe name. How can i store or keep recipe_ID with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the ComboBox items using directly the DataSource and control which field you want to display using the DisplayMember property. Together with the ValueMember property you could write

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....))
{
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM Recipe", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        recipeCombo.DataSource = dt;
        recipeCombo.DisplayMember = "Recipe_Name";
        recipeCombo.ValueMember = "Recipe_ID";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Now in the ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged event (or everywhere you need to know the RecipeID you just have to write

```
if(recipeCombo.SelectedItem != null)
{
    int recipeID = Convert.ToInt32(recipeCombo.SelectedValue);
    ... and use your value for insert without any JOIN
}
```

In whichever point you need, (for example in a SAVE button click event) add the following INSERT

```
if(recipeCombo.SelectedItem == null)
    .... error message and return....
else

string sql = @"INSERT INTO Ingredient 
     (Ingredient_Name, Ingredient_Amount, Recipe_ID) 
     VALUES (@IngredientName, @IngredientFirstname, @RecipeID)";
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IngredientName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ingredientTxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IngredientAmount", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ingredientAmount.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecipeID", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(recipeCombo.SelectedValue);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

PS. Do not use AddWithValue - [it is a shortcut with a lot of problems](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) -

Comment: Where you said "... and use your value for insert without any JOIN", what do you mean?

Comment: you use it directly as value for the _INSERT INTO Ingredient (Ingredient_Name,Ingredient_Amount.Recipe_ID ) VALUES (valueForIngredient, ValueForAmount, recipeID)_

Comment: I have updated your answer with my insert. Where would i put that along with the ComboBox_SelectedIndexChange event? as i want this to save when save btn is pressed

Comment: Just add the insert code in your button click event code. You can use the SelectedItem/SelectedValue pattern above in whichever point is more logically correct to do for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do **not** need a **JOIN** in your case because you have only one table "Recipe" that contains the data you need to find "Recipe_ID". **JOIN**s are used to "join" two tables.
2. If "Recipe_Name" is identical you can select the "Recipe_ID" where the "Recipe_Name" is equal to the selected value from the combobox then insert the new row to the "Ingredient" table.

   INSERT INTO **Ingredient** SELECT @Ingredient_Name, @Ingredient_Amount, Recipe_ID FROM **Recipe** WHERE Recipe_ID = @myComboboxSelectedValue

*Note: In this case **Recipe_ID** is redundant because you can remove it from your database and use **Recipe_Name** instead.*

3. If "Recipe_Name" is not identical so you will need to fetch "Recipe_ID" with it and store it in the code-behind (if you do not want to show it to the user) and use it in your insert query.

By the way:
4. Whether using MYSQL or SQLSERVER the solution is the same, so "using .mdf" in the title of the question is irrelevant.
5. ".mdf" files are the extensions for SQLSERVER databases.

Comment: @Steve, it is not an INSERT INTO with a WHERE. It is an INSERT INTO with a **SELECT WHERE**

Comment: Yes slipped on that, comment removed